# Why is the collision term negative in the equation of motion for a fluid of electrons in a plasma?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, plasma-physics

The fluid equation of motion for electrons in a cold plasma is 
\begin{equation}
m_en_e\frac{d\textbf{v}}{dt} = -en_e(\textbf{E}+\textbf{v}\times \textbf{B}) - m_en_e\nu\textbf{v}
\end{equation}
where $\nu$ is the collision frequency. Why is the collision term negative?

Comment: Where do you get your equations? The collision term as written implies that collisions cannot change the direction of the velocity, only the magnitude -- shouldn't it be something like $m_e n_e \nu (\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{v}$?

Comment: Or are you only considering 1D motion?

Comment: Sure, explaining the minus sign for 1D motion would work too. Just trying to understand why it is minus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a macroscopic description of collisions (with heavy ions) which treats them like a friction force that is opposite to the direction of motion of electron liquid.